# Is using forceUpdate slower than setState() in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I'm experimenting with building a ReactJS app that doesn't use ReactJS components state or props for display data. Instead I use props for passing models to the component so that it will bind `self` to it, and get re-rendered on model data change.

I would like to keep the component state ’clean’ in such way that the component's state would only contain data about user experience related stuff. If you are familiar with Firebase, the apps works very much like when building a react app using Firebase, but it should be more declarative.

Because I do not use `component.setState({...})` I would like to use `component.forceUpdate`. I have read many times that you shouldn't use this method because it skips the lifecycle methods, but this is an experiment.

What I'm mostly interested in right now is whether it is slower than `setState` and does ReactJS do the same smart DOM diffing when an update is forced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React's `forceUpdate()` is not slower than `setState()`.

It **uses the same smart DOM "diffing" algorithm**, so that component updates are predictable while being fast enough for high-performance apps.

Calling `forceUpdate()` will cause `render()` to be called on the component, skipping `shouldComponentUpdate()`. This will trigger the normal lifecycle methods for child components, including the `shouldComponentUpdate()` method of each child. React will still only update the DOM if the markup changes.

PS: Yes, normally you should try to avoid all uses of `forceUpdate()` and only read from `this.props` and `this.state` in the Component's `render()` method.